# Memory allocation in Java - Android

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, java-memory-model

If I have:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.create(..); // instance a
bitmap = Bitmap.create(...); // instance b
bitmap = null;
bitmap = Bitmap.create(...); // instance c
bitmap.recycle();
bitmap = Bitmap.create(...); // instance d
bitmap.recycle();
bitmap = null;
```

Once this code is executed, which of the 4 instances are still in memory? I know .recycle() instructs the native code to deallocate all resources to that object, but there's no guarantee of when that happens.

The reason I'm asking, is let's look at the following loop:

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;

while (true) {
    bitmap = Bitmap.create(...);    
}
```

This I assume will eventually crash the app (out of memory)? If so, how should this loop be rewritten? (If I'm using bitmap to animate and display changed state).

Comment: You can't know if those Bitmaps still remain in memory. I think if you call ````gb()```` after ````recycle()```` you can be sure that the last two are not in memory. [Android Developers:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29) ````This will not free the pixel data synchronously; it simply allows it to be garbage collected if there are no other references.````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java (and by extension Android) use asynchronous [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) to clean up allocated memory. The collector runs in the background freeing what memory it can. What this means is that at no point in time can you guarantee* how many unreachable objects have been cleaned up vs. those that are still pending.

Immediately after your first code block has finished executing it's possible all four `Bitmap` objects still exist on the heap, but at some point the garbage collector will run, determine that they're all no longer reachable, and free up their associated memory.

The same thing is true in your second code block; some arbitrary number of objects will still exist on the heap even though they are no longer reachable, however the GC will do its best to clean them up as this happens. In practice the GC is *very* good at cleaning up such short-lived objects, so it may even be able to keep pace with your loop (but that isn't a guarantee).

The JVM/ART will do its best to avoid an `OutOfMemory` situation, including an aggressive last-ditch garbage collection to attempt to reclaim any possible memory it can to keep the application running. Therefore it's unlikely your second loop would cause any issues, but it'd be easy enough for you to test.

Hopefully you're not literally creating and immediately discarding thousands of `Bitmap` objects; presumably they're being used for at least some period of time during which you aren't just creating more `Bitmap`s that literally go unused (if so, that's your problem).

<sub>* There are tricks, such as using [`PhantomReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html), which do let you monitor the status of garbage collection, however these will put more burden on the GC and thus aren't a good idea - or necessary - in general.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Android Uses DalvikVM which functions almost similar to Java. It does not recollect unless required.

[MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) is an excellent tool to analyze memeory dumps using hprof for android.

You can find answer yourself using MAT

Comment: " It does not recollect unless required." Yet my app (and MANY apps according to StackOverflow) are terminated due to Out of Memory Exceptions. So I would argue it's not doing a good job of recollecting.

Comment: I have used `Bitmaps` in android application and only instance it thrown `Out of Memory` was when I had not used `recycle()` properly. Which I could found out using MAT.